# how much degree to turn from my current location to my destination point

Tags: android, google-maps

how much degree I need to turn from my current location to destination point so that its in an straight line from current location.I am using Google Maps and I am getting latitude and longitude but I am unable to find How much degree I need to turn (Direction from current position to destination point). I am also using compass and getting Azimuth but I am unable to figure out .

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean how much to turn from the current direction you are facing?

Comment: Yes Stark that exactly what I wanted !! Please share any info if you know.Thanks.

Comment: From your current location to your destination IS a straight line by definition.

Comment: yes but is it straight line behind or on the right,left or straight ??

Comment: basically the arrow head which side its suppose to face so that its in a same path as the route(straight line)??

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android or programming, you need to learn some basic navigation skills. Read this: http://www.magazine.ordnancesurveyleisure.co.uk/magazine/tscontent/editorials/outdoor-skills/map-and-navigation-skills/using-a-compass.html

Comment: Is there any code in google maps /direction api as I wont be doing the reading ,the app needs to tell arduino robot and it should move in the direction of the destination by itself !!

Comment: @JasonWood If you are going going to put any effort into researching/learning then why should we help you?

Comment: I have tried many codes If you want I will paste them here for location sensor and maps and everything is fine if human is controlling it but if its suppose to control a robot then How will it read ??I know it can be done but unable to figure it out Or help me find out direction of the compass w.r.t destination point .Please .

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Maps API documentation:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

> google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(from:LatLng, to:LatLng)     number
>
> Returns the heading from one LatLng to another LatLng. Headings are
>   expressed in degrees clockwise from North within the range [-180,180).

Comment: Hello Sir can I use the above code in google maps v1 ?? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not much help there.  V2 has been deprecated since 2010, and v1 is even older.  I'm just curious, but why the need to work with either of those still?  Android will soon (November) not even allow calls to be made via v2.

Comment: I had implemented google maps around a year ago so I went ahead with whatever app version eclipse provided .Should I go with v3 now ?? and will my old code work here by copying and pasting?? Thank you for your reply Sir .

Comment: Also Sir how to start coding in Google maps v3 I already have a full functioning app with v1 now I will have to upgrade to v3 in Android ? any tutorial or reference.Thanks gain for your time nad effort Sir,really appreciate it.